# Bypass SQL COLLATE

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, collate

Is there a way to "bypass" the SQL collate logic? I want two different bytearrays to give me two different keys no matter what and without SQL trying to collate them.

I prefer to use the nvarchar data type if possible.

The most generic COLLATE setting I have found is 'Latin1_General_100_BIN2' but even that gives me a conflict in this example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test] (
    [Feature] [nvarchar](450) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Feature] ASC)
)

insert into test values ('a')
insert into test values ('a ')
```

I get the error

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.test'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.test'. The duplicate key value is (a ).
```

I am using the SQL server in MS Azure.

Comment: Trailing blanks have nothing to do with collations.

Comment: Use varbinary instead?

Comment: That's standard SQL rules - before two strings are compared for equality, the shorter string is padded with blanks. As jarlh says, nothing to do with collations.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Is there any way to bypass this (for nvarchar)?

Comment: You can have a computed column for the trimmed length, and include that column in the pk. Still a but unclear why you are doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend that you use the `Feature` field as the primary key.

If possible, you can try to use below script.

```
declare @tb table(id int identity,name varchar(20))
insert into @tb(name) values('a'),(' a'),('a ')
select * from @tb --where name=' a' and datalength(name)=datalength(' a')
```

**Running result:**

[image]

In the database, for spaces, currently only `len` and `datalength` can be used to filter data. When inserting data in the primary key, `space characters` should be filtered out. So it should not be supported.

For more details or questions, you can [raise a support on the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request), and the official will give you documentation or a satisfactory answer.